# Model predicting all classes as 1 on using binary cross entropy but predicts 2 classes accurately on using categorical cross entropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I tried building an image prediction model. When i used binary cross entropy with sigmoid and single output node, my model could predict only one class but gave higher accuracy whereas on using categorical cross entropy with softmax and two layers output node, model was able to predict both classes but had low accuracy.

How can I solve this problem?

In first case, the accuracy is around 91 while its 81 in second case

```
original_dataset_dir = '/content/train'
base_dir = '/content/new_folder'
os.mkdir(base_dir)

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
os.mkdir(train_dir)

test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')
os.mkdir(test_dir)

train_0_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'class 0')
os.mkdir(train_0_dir)

train_1_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'class 1')
os.mkdir(train_1_dir)

test_0_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'class 0')
os.mkdir(test_0_dir)

test_1_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, 'class 1')
os.mkdir(test_1_dir)


fnames = ['0.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_0_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

fnames = ['0.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000, 1500)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(test_0_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

fnames = ['1.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(train_1_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

fnames = ['1.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000, 1500)]
for fname in fnames:
    src = os.path.join(original_dataset_dir, fname)
    dst = os.path.join(test_1_dir, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)



print('total training class 0 images:', len(os.listdir(train_0_dir)))
print('total training class 1 images:', len(os.listdir(train_1_dir)))
print('total test class 0 images:', len(os.listdir(test_0_dir)))
print('total test class 1 images:', len(os.listdir(test_1_dir)))




from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                target_size=(150, 150), 
                                                batch_size=20,
                                                class_mode='binary')

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                                    target_size=(150, 150),
                                                    batch_size=20,
                                                    class_mode='binary')

from keras import layers
from keras import models


model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape= 
(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()


from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
          optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
          metrics=['acc'])
```

I have used 1000 images for training and 500 for testing. Confusion matrix for binary cross entropy:

```
Confusion Matrix
[[1000    0]
[1000    0]]

Classification Report
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

 class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67      1000
 class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00      1000

accuracy                           0.50      2000
macro avg       0.25      0.50     0.33      2000
weighted avg    0.25      0.50     0.33      2000
```

using categorical cross entropy -

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape= 
(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()


from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
          optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
          metrics=['acc'])
```

The confusion matrix for categorical cross entropy -

```
Confusion Matrix
[[505 495]
[545 455]]
Classification Report
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

 class 0       0.48      0.51      0.49      1000
 class 1       0.48      0.46      0.47      1000

accuracy                            0.48      2000
macro avg       0.48      0.48      0.48      2000
weighted avg    0.48      0.48      0.48      2000
```

Comment: Why do you care about accuracy metric when you can clearly see that in the first case the model didn't even try to predict classes? At least in the second version it looks like the model is trying.

Comment: @pavel I agree but i need a either or type of result in my output. When an image is fed, the result should be either 0 or 1. In order to achieve this i tried single output node but unfortunately the model predicts all images as 0

Comment: I am afraid that does not answer the (reasonable) question posed by @pavel

Comment: In first case, is there any way I can make the model predict better